# Where should I locate my baseActivity class?

Tags: android

Say i have com.mydomain.myappname. Is it a good idea to put my baseActivity class (from which all my other activity classes inherit) into com.mydomain? Or is that asking for trouble? I'm worried my other apps could then conflict if installed on the same phone.

Also, if not in com.mydomain, where should I place them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter where you put it since different apps don't have access to each others code / classes. You could place your common base Activity into a library project to simplify having several apps that use the same code.

Comment: Oh so if I have two apps, say com.domain.myapp1 and com.domain.myapp2, then neither can access the stuff in each other's com.domain package?

Comment: Correct. Each app brings it's own classes and can use the Android "framework.jar". Anything outside can't be accessed directly.